# Keep radio buttons and checkboxes selected after submitting form (webMathematica)

Tags: html, jsp, wolfram-mathematica

I have a couple radio buttons and a checkbox in my webMathematica form (jsp page).
After submitting the form, the radio buttons and checkbox are deselected. Is there a way to keep them selected after submitting the form?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is some sample code:

There are 4 radio buttons to select from. I would like to keep the radio button selected after submitting the form.

```
<input type="radio" name="pumptype" value="pump1"  ${param.PutorCall == "pump1" ? "checked" : ""} />
<input type="radio" name="pumptype" value="pump2" ${param.PutorCall == "pump2" ? "checked" : ""} />
<input type="radio" name="pumptype" value="pump3" ${param.PutorCall == "pump3" ? "checked" : ""} />
<input type="radio" name="pumptype" value="pump4" ${param.PutorCall == "pump4" ? "checked" : ""} />
```

Comment: Please show your existing code

Comment: I have no idea what `[wolram-mathematica]` tag is doing there on your question, but is it the technical reason that you're comparing to a request parameter named `PutorCall` instead of `pumptype`? This is otherwise a rather obvious mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to keep the form data intact even after sending it off to the server. Now, HTTP is a stateless protocol so it'll forget everything after a request. What you can do here is retrieve your data in server-side, do whatever you want to do with them, then pack the data that you originally received in a command object and send it with the response. Populate your form with the data from that command object. That's basically how it should be done.